# How do I change a code rule in SonarQube 4.0?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've just downloaded SonarQube 4.0, started it up with the in-memory database and logged in as administrator.
But I cannot change any of the code rules as described in the online documentation.
Is it because I haven't got a persistent data store (e.g. MySQL)?
Or...?

This is how it looks:
[image: Screenshot of SonarQube 4.0 with coding rules.]

**Update:**

How can I create new rules? That is also missing from the screenshot when compared with the current documentation.

Answer (score -1):

To answer my own question:

Follow the guide described [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules).
Basically, search for a deactivated rule "xpath" and make a copy. That rule serves as a template for making your own rules.

Comment: That's a very poor guide. Gives almost no information regarding the sonarqube specific syntax that you can access in your xpath expressions.